# Prompt hostname change command line

Tags: command-line, wmic

The code:

```
wmic computersystem where name="%COMPUTERNAME%" call rename name="NEW-NAME"
```

How do I change it to allow user input for the new name?

Answer (score 0):

```
set /p new_name=enter a new computer name :
wmic computersystem where name="%COMPUTERNAME%" call rename name="%new_name%"
```

Could you try this?

Answer (score 0):

My exact batch file contents that worked for me are below:

```
set /p new_name=enter a new computer name :
wmic computersystem where "name='%COMPUTERNAME%'" call rename name="%new_name%"
```

...
for a constant (JLT-) and a variable name.  I used the following

```
set /p new_name=enter a new computer name :
wmic computersystem where "name='%COMPUTERNAME%'" call rename name=JLT-"%new_name%"
```

I then placed the batch file in run once, to change the computer name post first boot.  As of windows 10 you can no longer do at as part of the first boot in windows 10 or in the unattend.xml in sysprep.